# SQL Stored Procedure Conversion Failed

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I am having trouble with a stored procedure that is pulling information from the built in C# role and membership management tables to my own custom made tables. The procedure works fine up until the last Update statement.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetPerpsectiveMemberList]
AS
DECLARE @Members TABLE
(
RowNumber INT,
PerspectiveMemberID INT,
FirstName varchar(MAX),
LastName varchar(MAX),
[Address] varchar(MAX),
City varchar(MAX),
[State] varchar(MAX),
Zip varchar(MAX),
Email varchar(MAX),
ASPMemberID varchar(MAX),
ASPUsername varchar(MAX),
RoleID2 varchar(MAX),
RoleName2 varchar(MAX)
)
INSERT INTO @Members
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Perspective_Member.PerspectiveMemberID), PerspectiveMemberID, Perspective_Member.FirstName, Perspective_Member.LastName, 
Perspective_Member.[Address], Perspective_Member.City, Perspective_Member.[State],   Perspective_Member.[State], Perspective_Member.Zip, Perspective_Member.ASPMemberID, 
Perspective_Member.ASPUsername,PerspectiveMemberID, ASPMemberID
FROM Perspective_Member
UPDATE @Members
SET RoleID2 = aspnet_UsersInRoles.RoleId
FROM aspnet_UsersInRoles
WHERE ASPMemberID = UserId
UPDATE @Members
SET RoleName2 = RoleName
FROM aspnet_Roles
WHERE RoleID2 = RoleID
SELECT * FROM @Members
```

When the procedure fails I get this message

```
Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier.
```

When I searched for this error message I found that everyone was having problems going from a string to the unique identifier but what is driving me crazy is that the only unique identifier being used in the last block is being used in the WHERE clause, and as I said earlier the procedure will run perfectly as long as the last UPDATE bl

Comment: Are you using **SQL = (Microsoft) SQL Server** ?? SQL really only is the structured query language - not a database product....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have Perspective_Member.[State] listed twice:

```
Perspective_Member.[State],   Perspective_Member.[State]
```

Here is corrected INSERT statement:

```
INSERT INTO @Members
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Perspective_Member.PerspectiveMemberID), 
        PerspectiveMemberID, 
        Perspective_Member.FirstName, 
        Perspective_Member.LastName,
        Perspective_Member.[Address], 
        Perspective_Member.City,
        Perspective_Member.[State], 
        Perspective_Member.Zip,
        Perspective_Member.Email, 
        Perspective_Member.ASPMemberID,
        Perspective_Member.ASPUsername,
        PerspectiveMemberID, 
        ASPMemberID
    FROM Perspective_Member
```

Also, you should change the data type for your ASPMemberID and RoleID2 fields in @Members table to `uniqueidentifier`.

Update: it appears that the error is due to `PerspectiveMemberID` value (INT) being inserted into RoleID2 column (uniqueidentifier).

Comment: Interesting that the insert does not fail, with too many columns in the select list.

Comment: Apparently it's getting inserted into Email field.

Comment: Yeah, that part clear, but given too many columns in the select list insert should have thrown an error before starting to process any data, and finding a conversion error.

Comment: Yes, but the number of fields actually matched, so INSERT statement executed successfully, the main issue is data type mismatch.

Comment: May not *have to* change to uniqueidentifier. Conversion from uniqueidentifier to varchar is implicit. But changing seems a good idea.

Comment: @BluesRockAddict -I changed RoleID2 and RoleName2 datatypes to uniqueidentifier, but I am still getting the same error message

Comment: What's the actual value of the PerspectiveMemberID? It appears that the error is due to PerspectiveMemberID value (INT) being inserted into RoleID2 column (uniqueidentifier).

Comment: It was the fact that both RoleID2 and RoleName2 were both either varchar or uniqueidentifier. When I changed RoleID2 to ui and left RoleName2 as varchar it worked. Thanks for your help you got me on the right track